# How to apply drawable shape Gradient to android.support.v7.widget.CardView in android

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, android-cardview

I can't set background gradient to **android.support.v7.widget.CardView**

Using `app:cardBackgroundColor="@somecolor"` this i only set background color, **not drawable resourse file**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/bg"> // not working in CardView

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

### bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="45" android:startColor="@android:color/black"
        android:endColor="@android:color/black"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:centerX="4"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 5):

This  is code using to Achieve your goal

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
        <!--Your View-->
  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I want to apply gradient to CardView not ChildView LinearLayout
I know applying background to LinearLayout is working properly but why i can't apply gradient to CardView?
Is there any reason ?

Comment: app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background" this property only accepts color

Comment: I know that `app:cardBackgroundColor` accepts only colors. Is there any programatically way to apply gradient to CardView?

Comment: i will try & what details are present inside of cardview

Comment: recently my app contains dummy data but in future it will contains map and dealers information and some other layout

Answer (score -5):

in code

```
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_sina_pay_bank_bg);
```